# Run action on load and stay on same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails

I am currently trying to run an action in my grails controller upon a page load in my application that will start a thread an continue with a task. I still have yet been able to successfully implement this in. This is my code:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var $form = $("#background_thread");
    $form.submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.post($(this).attr("background"), $(this).serialize(), function(data){
            alert("should work" + data)
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out why it's not working. Is there some simple syntax I'm overlooking or a different way I should be doing this?

Update:

My form id is `#background_thread` and I am trying to do it asynchronously so that the page will still stay the same and my action will be run.

My script is run but fails on `$form.submit(function(e){` and will not pass through.

Comment: You are submitting a form on page load??

Comment: I'm trying to either submit the form on page load an stay on the same page or run this specific action on load. The action just needs to be run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to prevent the default behaviour on the event that has been generated.

```
$form.submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // your code
}
```

Update:

You will certainly need to add the above regardless, once you get the overall script working. Also, please add your markup to the question. A few basic questions to make sure:

Is #background_thread the id of your form?

In your network tab in Chrome Inspector (or similar) is the request being fired off?

Is the markup being delivered asynchronously, as if it is, you will need to use .on to attach the event permanently, rather than just a basic selector?

Update 2:

Your form is being delivered asynchronously itself, therefore your event attaqchement must change to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("body").on("submit", "#background_thread", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.post($(this).attr("background"), $(this).serialize(), function(data){
            alert("should work" + data)
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

So, to explain, your event attachment was happening during document ready. Document ready fires, but the form hasn't been delivered to the DOM yet, so it doesn't have an attachment to it. Therefore, you use on() to permanently attach that event to that element for the lifetime of the entire page's rendering to the browser.

N.B. I attached it to body, to begin listening for submit at that point, in practice you would **not** do this for many reasons, you would attach it to the outermost point of AJAX replacement for the form, essentially, the nearest parent to the form that will be known on initial page load.

I hope that this has been of some use and good luck with your application.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. I did a little more debugging and found that once it hits `$form.submit(function()` it does not continue. Any ideas as to why this would occur?

Comment: Look in the console to see if there is an error in for example getting the URL to post to

Comment: Updated my answer to ask a few more questions that I hope will lead us to the answer.

Comment: If you can pause execution as it enters the for submit event, run $(this).attr("background") and $(this).serialize() through the console manually and see what happens. You also haven't yet stated whether any network packets get sent, or whether the form itself is delivered asynchronously, as I mentioned above, your related markup would be helpful.

Comment: When I run it manually it does nothing and the form itself is delivered asynchronously. Is there something terribly wrong that's occurring or I'm doing?

Comment: Thank you so much this helps a ton! But I need this to run on load of the page instead of on submit as it needs to call the action and run it while the user is still viewing the page.

Comment: When you deliver the form asynchronously, push a script snippet along with the markup you deliver at the bottom of your form: $("#background_thread").trigger("submit"); it will execute your event attachment as you have it.

Comment: That worked flawlessly thank you, but it does not stay on the same page. Instead when it is ran it brings up the `background` method and throws a 404 because a page does not exist. My whole goal of all of this was to run the action and stay on the same page. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: You need to take "data" within your post function and put it to use. If it's markup, put it somewhere into a div ("#targetDiv").html(data); If it's JSON, you need to parse it and deal with it. Make sense? P.S. Am I on commission yet?!

Comment: Sorry I should've been more specific. Even inside the post when I have `alert("should work" + data)` it's not called, nor is my markup handling `$("#users").html(data)`. That's what I was wondering as to why it's still redirecting to the method.

Comment: There isn't much more I can help you with, without having full disclosure on your markup and surrounding code.

Comment: Found the error. Thank you so much for your patience and help